# Winform DataGridView still shows data after final update

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, datagridview

I'm developing a winform application using C#.net, using `DataGridView` to display the data, but after the last update, the `DataGridView` returns 1 last row, but i want my `DataGridView` to return a blank row or just show the header only...

nb: Before the update JmlKirimK value is 1.

```
                try
                {
                    con.Close();
                    con.Open();
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select PasienID, NoHP, JmlKirimK from datapasien where JmlKirimK ='1' AND StatusDiabetes='Ya'", con);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        con.Close();
                        con.Open();
                        nohp = Convert.ToString(dr[1]);
                        idpasien = Convert.ToString(dr[0]);
                        jml = Convert.ToString(dr[2]);
                        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                        if (objclsSMS.sendMsg(this.port2, nohp, this.txtisi.Text))
                        {
                           MySqlCommand cmd3 = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE datapasien SET JmlKirimK='2' Where PasienID='" + idpasien.Trim() + "'", con);
                           cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                           terkirim = terkirim + 1;
                           showgridkirimulang();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           tdkterkiri = tdkterkiri + 1;
                        }

                        showgridkirimreset();
                    }
                    con.Close();
                    alert.ContentImage = SmsGatewayProlanis.Properties.Resources.Warning1;
                    alert.CaptionText = "Status";
                    alert.ContentText = "Pesan Terkirim = " + terkirim + ", Pesan Tidak Terkirim = " + tdkterkiri;
                    alert.Show();


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    alert.ContentImage = SmsGatewayProlanis.Properties.Resources.Warning1;
                    alert.CaptionText = "Status";
                    alert.ContentText = ex.Message;
                    alert.Show();
                    ErrorLog(ex.Message);
                }
```

This is my `DataGridView` code

```
        private void showgridkirimulang()
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT NamaPasien, RiwayatPenyakit, AlamatPasien, UmurPasien, Jeniskelamin, NoHP, JmlKirimK, StatusDiabetes FROM datapasien WHERE JmlKirimK=1 AND StatusDiabetes='Ya'", con);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                gridkirimulang.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                gridkirimulang.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Nama Pasien";
                gridkirimulang.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Riwayat Penyakit";
                gridkirimulang.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Alamat Pasien";
                gridkirimulang.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Umur Pasien";
                gridkirimulang.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Jenis Kelamin";
                gridkirimulang.Columns[5].HeaderText = "No. HP";
                gridkirimulang.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Jumlah Pesan Terkirim";
                gridkirimulang.Columns[7].HeaderText = "Status Diabetes";
                gridkirimulang.MasterGridViewTemplate.BestFitColumns();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: What you mean under "gridview return 1"?

Comment: i mean return 1 last data, even though i want my gridview return blank data cause after update JmlKirimK set to 2, but if i close my project and re-run, my gridview showing blank

Comment: bind to your `DataSource` `null` like this: `gridkirimulang.DataSource = null;`

Comment: thx it's working, but my system is sms gateway so if my message sent is ok, but if it's not or not send JmlKirimK stay in 1, and my datagridview show blank too if i used Datasource = null, even though my datagrid show data that JmlKirimK = 1...
sorry my english is bad